# Not to yield for what is being said

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the behaviour of kids called when they don't listen to you and end after getting what they want? Such as, your kid has a cold. He wants to icecream. You don't give him money. But he is crying and insisting on getting money. Which of the following is suitable?

```
The kid is showing stubbornness.


The kid sticks out for icecream.


The kid ends after getting icecream.
```

My actual concern is the verb form of the adj 'stubborn' that I've not been able to find.

Comment: The first two you could probably say `The kid is being stubborn`, or possibly the `The kid is holding out for icecream`. The last sentence I can't tell what you are going for, but it makes no sense as is.

Comment: Something like *demanding*, *obsessing*, *pining*, *fussing*, or even *rebelling*?

Comment: @ Jason Bassford Actually what I want to ask about is the verb for 'stubborn'. We say: His behaviour is bad. He misbehaves. Now, what here? He is stubborn. He??? what verb?

Comment: I can't think of any verb with the exact meaning of _to be stubborn_. He _persists in demanding_ ice cream?

Comment: @Kate Bunting The problem is my writing is for kids and I think 'persist' is kind of difficult word for kids.

Comment: My sentence is: When my father refuses to give me money, I stick out for it until I get it. Does it make sense?

Comment: It would have been useful to know that you were writing for children! By the way, it's _ends up_, not _ends after_.